# Are .NET modules thread safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, module, thread-safety

I have a .NET module that I need to call from an instantiated class.  Can I count on only one object at a time being able to access the functions in a module (something like instantiating a module) or will I need to look at locking within the class?  I can't seem to get a clear answer to this anywhere.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the term "module"? Are you talking about classes which implement `System.Web.IHttpModule`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends entirely on the implementation of the classes in the module. As a general rule, though, if they're not advertised as thread-safe, they're probably not.

Comment: As an addition: MSDN documentation nearly always specifies thread safety information for all classes in the base class library.

Answer (score 2):

The term "Module" typically refers to a binary file, and they are merely containers of types. These types may or may not be thread-safe.

In general, no types in .NET are thread-safe unless they are made thread safe.